# Search key of big partition in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

nodetool cfstats/tablestats shows the "Compacted partition maximum bytes"

Now how to find the key of this partition or other huge partitions ?

The purpose is to analyse why these partitions are growing big and correct the data model accordingly.

I have seen it's possible to see these partition keys in logs, but unfortunately my logs are periodically removed.

Comment: You can use the instaclustr tools https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/tools/ic-tools-for-cassandra-sstables/

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [nodetool toppartitions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsToppartitions.html) command which is supposed to show you the most active partitions. Sometimes it helps to analyze and manage your data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the instaclustr tools

https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/tools/ic-tools-for-cassandra-sstables/

The following command is useful for finding big partitions:

`ic-pstats [-n <num>] [-t <snapshot>] [-f <filter>] <keyspace> <column-family>`

```
-n <num>    Number of partitions to display in leaders lists
-t <name>   Snapshot to analyse (snapshot name from nodetool listsnapshots). Snapshot is created if none is specified.
-f <files>  Comma separated list of Data.db sstables to filter on
```

Another useful tool is sstable-tools:

https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools

It has a describe command that show the widest and largest partitions

```
java -jar sstable-tools.jar describe ma-2-big-Data.db
```

The output is like this:

```
/Users/clohfink/git/sstable-tools/./src/test/resources/ma-2-big-Data.db
=======================================================================
Partitions: 1
Rows: 1
Tombstones: 0
Cells: 4
Widest Partitions:
   [frodo] 1
Largest Partitions:
   [frodo] 104 (104 B)
Tombstone Leaders:
Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
Bloom Filter FP chance: 0.010000
Size: 50 (50 B)
Compressor: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor
  Compression ratio: -1.0
Minimum timestamp: 1455937221199050 (02/19/2016 21:00:21)
Maximum timestamp: 1455937221199050 (02/19/2016 21:00:21)
SSTable min local deletion time: 2147483647 (01/18/2038 21:14:07)
SSTable max local deletion time: 2147483647 (01/18/2038 21:14:07)
TTL min: 0 (0 milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an external tool like `Apache drill` or `presto-db` to run a query like :

```
SELECT key1, key2, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY key1, key2
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Where `key1` and `key2` are part of your partition key.

This query will get the top 10 partitions by size.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to do that with spark, that leads to others problems sadly.